# Flex box dynamic width and height

Tags: flexbox, react-native

I am trying to create a messages view using react-native e.g.:

[image]

As you can see:

1. The bubbles have a dynamic width and height based on the content
2. There is a maximum width for the bubbles and they grow downwards

I am trying to recreate this using react native, however I am only able to acheive (2) and not sure how to go about acheiving both.. this is what i have thus far:

[image]

```
  <View style={{flex:1,backgroundColor:'blue',flexDirection:'row'}}>
     <View style={{backgroundColor:'orange'}}>
            <View style={{width:90,flex:1}}>
              <Text>123</Text>
              </View>
     </View>
     <View style={{flex:0.25,backgroundColor:'red'}}>
              <Text>123</Text>
     </View>
  </View>
```

If I increase the orange view to represent a big bubble then it just goes off the screen... e.g.:

[image]

Comment: May be not useful as per coding.
But seems it wont work for dynamic content , works with static content only ...

Answer (score 15):

I was having same issue. I tried many things including putting wrappers here-and-there (like mentioned in previous answers). None of them worked.

@André Junges's answer is not correct because @kingkong and I have different requirements.

Then, I saw that flex can also take value -1. And setting it solved the problem.

Here is the code:

```js
const messages = [
              'hello',
              'this is supposed to be a bit of a long line.',
              'bye'
              ];
return (
  <View style={{
            position: 'absolute',
            top: 0,
            left: 0,
            width: 150,
            alignItems: 'flex-end',
            justifyContent: 'flex-start',
            backgroundColor: '#fff',
            }}>

{messages.map( (message, index) => (
  <View key={index} style={{
                  flexDirection: 'row',
                  marginTop: 10
                }}>
    <View style={{
                  flex: -1,
                  marginLeft: 5,
                  marginRight: 5,
                  backgroundColor: '#CCC',
                  borderRadius: 10,
                  padding: 5,
                }}>
      <Text style={{
                    fontSize: 12,
                    }}>
        {message}
      </Text>
    </View>
    <Image source={require('some_path')} style={{width:30,height:30}} />
   </View> 
  ))} 
 </View>
)
```

And here is the result:

[image: And here is the result:]

Comment: Do you know how you'd set a max width, as presented in OP's example?

Answer (score 4):

I've come up with a somewhat contrived way of doing this. Let's look at the problem first.

We can use flexbox to put the "badge" on the left and the text on the right, then have "message rows" going down horizontally. That's easy, but what we want is for the message row to change width depending on its content, and flexbox won't let you do that as it greedily expands to fill all of the space.

What we need is a way of checking the width of the message text then resizing the view accordingly, forcing it to a specified width. We can't use `measure` to get the text width since that actually only gives us the width of the underlying node, not the actual text itself.

To do this I stole an idea [from here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/901) and created a bridge to Obj-C which creates a UILabel with the text and gets its width that way.

```
//  TextMeasurer.h
#import "RCTBridgeModule.h"
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface TextMeasurer : NSObject<RCTBridgeModule>

@end


//  TextMeasurer.m
#import "TextMeasurer.h"

@implementation TextMeasurer

RCT_EXPORT_MODULE();

RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(get:(NSString *)text cb:(RCTResponseSenderBlock)callback)
{
  UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc]init];
  label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:14.0];
  label.text = text;

  callback(@[[NSNumber numberWithDouble: label.intrinsicContentSize.width]]);
}

@end
```

I then wrapped the usage of this into a component:

```
var AutosizingText = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            width: null
        }
    },

    componentDidMount() {
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.refs.view.measure((x, y, width, height) => {
                TextMeasurer.get(this.props.children, len => {
                    if(len < width) {
                        this.setState({
                            width: len
                        });
                    }
                })
            });
        });
    },

    render() {
        return <View ref="view" style={{backgroundColor: 'red', width: this.state.width}}><Text ref="text">{this.props.children}</Text></View>
    }
});
```

All this will do is resize the containing view if the width of the text is less than the original width of the view - which will have been set by flexbox. The rest of the app looks like this:

```
var messages = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        var rows = [
            'Message Text',
            'Message Text with lots of content ',
            'Message Text with lots of content put in here ok yeah? Keep on talking bla bla bla whatever is needed to stretch this message body out.',
            'Keep on talking bla bla bla whatever is needed to stretch this message body out.'
        ].map((text, idx) => {
            return <View style={styles.messageRow}>
                <View style={styles.badge}><Text>Me</Text></View>
                <View style={styles.messageOuter}><AutosizingText>{text}</AutosizingText></View>
            </View>
        });

        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                {rows}
            </View>
        );
    }
});

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'flex-start',
    alignItems: 'stretch',
    flexDirection: 'column',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  messageRow: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    margin: 10
  },
  badge: {
    backgroundColor: '#eee',
    width: 80, height: 50
  },
  messageOuter: {
    flex: 1,
    marginLeft: 10
  },
  messageText: {
    backgroundColor: '#E0F6FF'
  }
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('messages', () => messages);
```

And it gives you this:

[image]

I would keep an eye on the [Github issue](http://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/901) as this solution is definitely a bit clunky and at the very least I'd expect to see a better way of measuring text in RN at some point.

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is from a year ago, but I had a similar issue and I think it can be useful for other devs.

So what I was trying to achieve was to create boxes like the image below where I would have a text in the left, and an arrow in the right.
Note that the boxes should have a `auto` height - since the text can be multiple lines..

[image]

JSX

```
<View style={styles.container}>
  <View style={styles.textContainer}>
    <Text style={styles.text}>{props.message.text}</Text>
  </View>
  <View style={styles.iconContainer}>
    <Icon name="chevron-right" size={30} color="#999" />
  </View>
</View>
```

Styles

```
container: {
  flex: 1,
  flexDirection: 'row',
  alignItems: 'center',
  backgroundColor: '#FFF',
  marginBottom: Metrics.baseMargin,
  borderRadius: 3,
},
textContainer: {
  flex: 1,
  flexDirection: 'column',
  paddingVertical: 30,
  paddingHorizontal: Metrics.doubleBaseMargin,
},
text: {
  color: '#333',
},
iconContainer: {
  width: 35,
  borderLeftWidth: 1,
  borderLeftColor: '#ddd',
  justifyContent: 'center',
  alignItems: 'center',
  alignSelf: 'stretch',
},
```

And of course, it didn't work. For some reason if I had an parent with `flexDirection: 'row'` the child wouldn't grow. **The text was being wrapped in multiple lines, but the parent's height (`.textContainer`) wasn't growing - and the text was being displayed even outside the container in some cases.** You can see it in the image below ( third message ).

[image]

### The fix was to wrap this whole component with one more `View`, like the code below:

```
<View style={styles.wrapper}>
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <View style={styles.textContainer}>
      <Text style={styles.text}>{props.message.text}</Text>
    </View>
    <View style={styles.iconContainer}>
      <Icon name="chevron-right" size={30} color="#999" />
    </View>
  </View>
</View>
```

The `.wrapper` class has only styles details on it (moved from `.container`)

```
wrapper: {
  backgroundColor: '#FFF',
  marginBottom: Metrics.baseMargin,
  borderRadius: 3,
},
```

Answer (score 1):

So I think the strategy here is that you want to contain the message bubble inside a full width block, then have two inner views. One inner view attempts to be as thin as possible, that's the one you put text in. The other tries to be as wide as possible, thus condensing the other block just wide enough to contain the text.

```
<View style={{flex:1,backgroundColor:'blue',flexDirection:'row'}}>
  <View style={{flex:0,backgroundColor:'red'}}>
    <Text>123</Text>
  </View>
  <View style={{backgroundColor:'orange', flex: 1}}/> 
</View>
```

Comment: Hi - this is what I was playing around with in my above example, however the problem is restricting the size of the flex we want to be dynamic width and then have it grow in height instead of pushing the other flex out of the view.. which is what is happening now..

Comment: @kingkong You can probably set a maxWidth on the element contained within the red box if you'd like to limit the width.

Comment: don't think maxWidth is implemented in react-native ... :(